# Content Security Policy blocking AJAX but the domain is valid

Tags: javascript, ajax, content-security-policy

I'm using Firefox console to run some JS from a github page (`https://github.com/user/repo/pull/1/files` specifically).

I'd like to be able to load the content of a file of the repo, and for that I'm using

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "https://github.com/user/repo/raw/master/path-to-file", true);
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
     alert(client.responseText + client.responseURL);
}
client.send();
```

The problem is that the content actually is at `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/path-to-file` and the url I'm loading (which is the one the `Raw` button points to in the github webpage) is redirecting to that one.

Firefox errors in the console with:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/path-to-file
(“connect-src https://github.com https://uploads.github.com
https://status.github.com https://collector.githubapp.com
https://api.github.com https://www.google-analytics.com
https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com wss://live.github.com”).
```

Is there a way to load that file in some way?

I think I need to run the request from the github page so that a file is accessible even if it's in a private repo (since the session of the user is used when sending the request).

I'm sending a request to a page that it's in the CSP, and that page does the redirect, so I don't see why the CSP should block me as I didn't try to access an "unauthorized" resource.

The alternative would be to load the github web page at `https://github.com/user/repo/blob/master/path-to-file`, but that means I'd have to parse it to remove all the displaying tags, and it's brittle as every change to github might break the script.